# Django Forms forms.DateInput / forms.DateField: formatting inconsistency between {{ form.datefield }} and {{ form.datefield.value }} in template code

Tags: python, django

my settings.py:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de'
TIME_ZONE = require_env("TIME_ZONE_IDENTIFIER")
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True


DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
    '%d.%m.%Y', '%d.%m.%y',  # European
    '%Y-%m-%d',  # ISO (for native mobile datepickers)
    '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y',  # US
    '%d %b %Y', '%d %B %Y',  # some long formats
]

DATE_FORMAT = 'j F Y'
TIME_FORMAT = 'H:i'
DATETIME_FORMAT = 'j F Y H:i'
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT = 'F Y'
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT = 'j F'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT = 'j N Y'
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = 'j N Y H:i'
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK = 1
```

forms.py:

```
class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):

    birth_date = forms.DateField(
        widget=forms.DateInput(
            format='%Y-%m-%d',
            attrs={
                "class": "form-control text-input",
            }
        ),
        input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS,
        initial=datetime.datetime.today,
        # required=False,
        # label=_("birth date"),
    )
```

now, if I want to construct the input myself in the template I would do:

```
 <input name="{{ form.birth_date.name }}" id="{{ form.birth_date.id_for_label }}"
                           class="form-control text-input" type="text"
                           value="{{ form.birth_date.value }}"
                           {% if form.birth_date.field.required %}required{% endif %}/>
```

In the image below you can see the difference between the above template code and `{{ form.birth_date }}`:

[image]

`{{ form.birth_date }}` the bottom grey box, respects the formatting, `{{ form.birth_date.value }}` the upper green box, doesnt.

Can this be explained somehow or should I add this to the Django bug tracker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference between including a `field` instance or the `field` instance's `field.value` in the template.

When you render a *`field` instance* in the template, it's widget's [`Widget.render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.render) method is called, and as a result, the [`Widget.format_value`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#DateInput) method is called.

This last method actually renders the [python date object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#date-objects) into a string using the [`localize_input` helper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.format_value). Here's the relevant part of that function:

```
def localize_input(value, default=None):
    # ...
    elif isinstance(value, datetime.date):
        value = datetime_safe.new_date(value)
        format = force_str(default or get_format('DATE_INPUT_FORMATS')[0])
        return value.strftime(format)
```

As seen above, the format you specify (or the first value in `DATE_INPUT_FORMATS`) is used.

However, when you access the [field.value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField.value) attribute, you actually get the ["raw" python date value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/_modules/django/forms/boundfield/#BoundField.value) (despite the misleading documentation). When the template evaluates the variable node, according to your example it uses your [`DATE_FORMAT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format) setting, as the docs mention:

> The default formatting to use for displaying date fields in any part of the system

If you want to render the value in a different format, you can do so easily with the [`date` template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#date); like so:

```
{{form.birth_date.value|date:"%Y-%m-%d"}} == {{form.birth_date}}
```

Or change the system wide default by updating the setting:

```
DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d"
```

Comment: So there does not seem to be any way to get the properly formatted value if you are rendering the field yourself, for instance ```<input id="{{ field.id_for_label }}" name="{{ field.name }}" class="form-control" value="{{ field.value | date:'Y-m-d' }}">```: you have to be able to check that this is a ``DateInput`` field...

Comment: I haven't done any thorough research, but I think most of the widgets use the `{{ widget.value|stringformat:'s' }}` filter https://github.com/django/django/blob/8208381ba6a3d1613bb746617062ccf1a6a28591/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets/input.html#L1